# How to get rid of security warning in Batch/Powershell

Tags: windows, security, powershell, batch-file, execution

[image]I am trying to execute a powershell script via batch file and constantly getting the following warning;

-> the execution policy is set to remote signed ; i also tested with Unrestricted, the same error shows up; how to get rid of this?

Comment: At a powershell prompt type get-help about_Execution_Policies

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/728332/5314 (possible dup)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8597794/5314 (How to write CMD files that automatically run themselves as PowerShell).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is your ps1 script reside in a network share ? You can skip all the security process by typing `set-executionpolicy bypass` in a admin powershell console

or you can invoke your script by `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file \\servername\share\script.ps1`

Comment: Please use the second one. The first uses global state to solve a local problem.

Answer (score 5):

If the same error shows up, make sure you're setting the execution policy in the right place.  On a 64 bit system there will be an execution policy for both 64 and 32  bit versions of Powershell. Normally, it loads the 64 bit version for the console, but uses the 32 bit version if called from a bat file.  You need to launch the 32 bit version, running eleveated, and set the execution policy for it also.