# How can I make html open a lua file or open a exe?

Tags: html, lua, exe

I need to know if I can make a html file open a lua file, like open it with the default program the computer is set to open those files with.
(Alternatively could I say "Open this file with this .exe" and I can just have the exe be the program I have set to open lua files with.)
This is what I have, it opens it like a text file though.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            MaGa
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href=".\MaGa.html" target="_self">Go to MaGa</a>
        <a href=".\MaGa.lua" target="_self">Open MaGa</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## local website with IE

start.bat

```
start lua myfile.lua
```

start.html

```
<a href="start.bat">start</a>
```

Remove Internet Explorer Open or Save Popup:

https://jwcooney.com/2014/03/31/remove-internet-explorer-open-or-save-popup/

Comment: What do you mean must be performed in the operating system? The html file is on my computer I'm not making a website I'm just making a program for my personal use so all the files are on my computer, I know lua really well and am trying to learn html, since lua has no ui, so is there no way to have my html open my lua file?

Comment: the assignment to open lua-files with your .exe

Comment: "Imagine if someone could run

format c:\
whenever you visted this website." but its not a website I'm just making .html files in a folder for me to use for something, is it still impossible?

Comment: you can try  <a href="test.bat">test</a>

Comment: I'm using chrome but I can switch to IE, how can I make it open batch files and can batch files open my lua files

Comment: Alright so it works kinda, I need to skip the part where it asks if you want to run or save the file and automatically just run and then it should be good.

Comment: you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817141/how-to-get-rid-of-security-warning-in-batch-powershell or https://jwcooney.com/2014/03/31/remove-internet-explorer-open-or-save-popup/

Comment: You are the best, thanks so much for your help! This is a pretty funny set up, where html opens batch files that open lua files and lua files make html files and open html files and repeat, but since I'm just doing this for fun it doesn't matter haha.